# Why can't I add a custom domain for an app using Developers Console?

Tags: google-app-engine, ssl, subdomain

I used to add custom domains through Google Apps (https://admin.google.com) and had no problems.

I am now told that it must be done through Google Developers Console (https://console.developers.google.com)

I follow the instructions (https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/using-custom-domains-and-ssl#adding_a_custom_domain_for_your_application) however after clicking 'add' nothing happens, no message, no error, I looked in the network tab and can see that when I click 'add' the following entries show:

A POST request: https://console.developers.google.com/m/domains?pid=my-project-id

```
Form Data: pid:my-project-id
           fqdn:mysub.mydomain.net.au
```

2x GET request for google analytics

I have changed my project id and domain above.

I have tried with Google Chrome and Internet Explorer.
I have tried clearing my cache, logging out of my Google account, spam clicking (hey you never know), disabling addons.
I have SSL for this domain, and have other apps working fine on it.

Any ideas as to why this is not working or at least showing me an error?

Update: The custom domain seems to be working now, however it does not show it in the custom domain list like my other apps so I have no idea what custom domains are setup

Comment: Any plugin like adblockers ?

Comment: @greg I tried disabling addons and used different browsers

Comment: You can use the [HAR analyzer](https://toolbox.googleapps.com/apps/har_analyzer/) tool to check the HTTP activity in your browser while this is happening. Look for the HTTP *responses*, which might have more information.

Comment: @Nick I looked at the chrome developer tools and see the three request mentioned but I don't see a response. I will give this tool a try and let you know

Comment: If you don't see a response, this could be because of network latency, and you may eventually see a time-out if you stay on the page.